# derived instance in base class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class baseClass
{
    derivedClass nm = new derivedClass();
}

class derivedClass : baseClass
{
}
```

This code builds fine. What might be the possible reason for C# to allow creating `derivedClass` objects in `baseClass`. Can you think of any specific reasons for doing this?

Comment: Why do you think C# should restrict that ?

Comment: Do you know any Object-Oriented language that restricts that? There is nothing special about it.

Comment: I am not able to think of a reason for creating `derivedClass` instance in `baseClass`. So I am wondering why C# allows it?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn: nope.. i do not know any language restricting this. But why don't they restrict if it will not be useful? If for some reason we can use this, please tell me the reason.

Comment: Not being able to think of a usage is not a good reason to prohibit something. The number of times I find classes which are sealed because the original dev couldn't think of a case that you would inherit it...

Comment: if some one has given you a yellow marker, you can use it to write something on common marker itself. why u think the world should stop you doing that?

Comment: My point of view for this was similar to this "An abstract
method contains no body and is, therefore, not implemented by the base class. Thus, a
derived class must override it—it cannot simply use the version defined in the base class.
As you can probably guess, an abstract method is automatically virtual, and there is no
need to use the virtual modifier. In fact, **it is an error to use virtual and abstract together**." (phrase from complete reference book). Well, now looking at the use cases for this, I think I am fine with it now..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This code builds fine.

Yes - why do you think it wouldn't?

> What might be the possible reason for C# to allow creating derivedClass objects in baseClass.

Because there's no reason to prohibit it?

> Can you think of any specific reasons for doing this?

Static factory methods, for example?

```
// BaseClass gets to decide which concrete class to return
public static BaseClass GetInstance()
{
    return new DerivedClass();
}
```

That's actually a pretty common pattern. We use it a lot in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) for example, where `CalendarSystem` is a public abstract class, but all the concrete derived classes are internal.

Sure, it's crazy to have the exact example you've given - with an instance field initializing itself by creating an instance of a derived class - because it would blow up the stack due to recursion - but that's not a matter of it being a derived class. You'd get the same thing by initializing the *same* class:

```
class Bang
{
    // Recursively call constructor until the stack overflows.
    Bang bang = new Bang();
}
```

Comment: :its not factory method if its static, you may want to write static factory or Creation Method.

Comment: @Saurabh: Changed to "static factory method" but I'm not sure there's much benefit in the distinction here, to be honest.

Comment: :i have read somewhere about the difference which is as follows  Creation Method: A static or non static method that creates (or clones) an instance of a class. 
Factory Method : A method defined and implemented in a hierarchy to supply polymorphic creation of some class type.

Comment: @Saurabh: Well the Wikipedia page on factory methods includes similar examples, which they call "static factory methods". They point out that it doesn't comply with the Factory Method Pattern as there's no polymorphism, but the meaning is pretty clear IMO. (Btw, why are you prefixing your comments with ":"?)

Comment: @user1416420: In what way does "Sure, it's crazy to have the exact example you've given because it would blow up the stack due to recursion" not clearly state that the stack will blow?

Comment: @user1416420: I don't think I'm implying that at all, because I talk about "the exact example you've given" which doesn't use a factory method. I'll clarify, but I really don't think the implication is there if you read what I've written...

Answer (score 1):

A developer I used to work with produced this code in our codebase. I personally agree its useful.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo MagicalFooValue
    {
        get { return Bar.Instance; }
    }

    private class Bar : Foo
    {
        //Implemented as a private singleton
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious case is to have a factory method in the base class returning appropriate implementations based on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

`derivedClass` can be instantiated in `baseClass` because it is an accessible class. There is no reason why c# should restrict you from doing so. Likewise, you can create an instance of `baseClass` within `baseClass` itself.